# How i can hide the user name parameter in url

Tags: javascript, urlrewriter

In registration form once entered user name and password it will redirect to user profile page. How i can hide that particular username parameter in that url

Comment: [See Accepted Answer of this Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/need-to-pass-the-values-as-hidden-in-url-in-salesforce)

Comment: Is this you? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94950/how-to-hide-username-parameter-in-profile-page - if so please do not post multiple questions under different usernames