# Adding http post to a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, httprequest

I'm trying to use an http post request to send data from one visualforce page to another since I'm using different controllers.  You can see in the code below I have another form tag and output panel to handle the post.  The idea being that when they click the update button the controller sets the values in "selectedValues" sets showform to true and rerenders the output panel post form.  Which should then show the inner panel and have the javascript post the internal form and then redirect to the next page.

The outputpanel rerenders but the javascript doesn't seem to fire.  After the rerender I inspect the page and notice that a console.log(document.forms) doesn't include the new form in the html collection.  Not sure if that is the problem or not.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="MyCustomObject__c" extensions="MycontrollerExtension" tabStyle="MyObject__c" recordSetVar="myValues">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:sectionHeader title="HeaderVal" subtitle="Update"/>
<apex:outputPanel id="message">
    <apex:pagemessages/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:pageBlock title="Filter Options">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons id="filter_buttons">
       <apex:commandButton value="Filter" action="{!search}" reRender="resultsPanel,message" status="searchStatus"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Clear Filter" action="{!clearFilter}" reRender="resultsPanel,message,filters" status="searchStatus"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="filters">
      <apex:selectList value="{!selectedstatusFilter}" multiselect="true" size="5">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!statusFilter}"/>
        </apex:selectList> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>   
<apex:pageBlock title="Applications">
  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
    <apex:actionStatus id="searchStatus">
      <apex:facet name="start">
        <apex:image value="/img/loading.gif"/>
      </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
    <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!update}" reRender="postForm"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:outputPanel id="resultsPanel" >
  <apex:pageMessage rendered="{!results.size == 0}" severity="info" summary="No results found"/>
  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!results != null && results.size > 0}">
      <c:MyComponent pController="{!ctrl}" panel="resultsPanel" id="theComponent"/>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Results}" var="con">
        <apex:column headerValue="Select">
          <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!con.selected}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.myObject.FieldSets.displayFields}" var="f">
          <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">
              <c:MyComponent2 sController="{!ctrl}" header="{!f.Label}" column="{!f.FieldPath}" panel="resultsPanel"/>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!con.jobApplication[f]}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:repeat>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="postForm">
      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showForm}">
        <script>
          window.onload = function(){
             postForm();
          }
         function postForm(){
           document.forms[0].submit();
         }
       </script>
       <form id="here" name="attack" action="{!$Page.MyNextPage}" >
         <input type="hidden" name="ticket_number" value="{!selectedValues}"/>
       </form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here but the normal way to go from one VF page to another is with a commandButton(link) whose `action="{!URLFOR(theNextPage,theIdOfObject,[params])}"` - check doc for how URLFOR works

Comment: Won't that pass the params in the url of the second page?  I'm trying to pass up to 200 ids to the next page.  So what I'm trying to do is use an http post to hide the ids in a hidden field that can then be accessed from the next page.

Comment: ah, this link (using cookies) could be the way to go: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/81325/2602